# Most efficient way to put fields of an embedded document in its parent for an entire MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am looking for the most efficient way to modify all the documents of a collection from this structure:

```
{
  [...]
  myValues:
  {
     a: "any",
     b: "content",
     c: "can be found here"
  }
  [...]
}
```

so it becomes this:

```
{
   [...]
   a: "any",
   b: "content",
   c: "can be found here"
   [...]
}
```

Basically, I want everything under the field `myValues` to be put in its parent document for all the documents of a collection.

I have been looking for a way to do this in a single query using `dbCollection.updateMany()`, put it does not seem possible to do such thing, unless the content of `myValues` is the same for all documents. But in my case the content of `myValues` changes from one document to the other. For example, I tried:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').updateMany({ myValues: { $exists: true } }, { $set: '$myValues' });
```

thinking it would perhaps resolve the `myValues` object and use that object to set it in the document. But it returns an error saying it's illegal to assign a string to the `$set` field.

So what would be the most efficient approach for what I am trying to do? Is there a way to update all the documents of the collection as I need in a single command?

Or do I need to iterate on each document of the collection, and update them one by one?

For now, I iterate on all documents with the following code:

```
var documents = await myCollection.find({ myValues: { $exists: true } });
for (var document = await documents.next(); document != null; document = await documents.next())
{
    await myCollection.updateOne({ _id: document._id }, { $set: document.myValues, $unset: { myValues: 1} });
}
```

Since my collection is very large, it takes really long to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html#replace-existing-collection) as an alternative, single-command solution. It can be used to replace existing collection with the output of an aggregation. Knowing that you can write following aggregation pipeline:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $mergeObjects: [ "$$ROOT", "$myValues" ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            myValues: 0
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "myCollection"
    }
])
```

[$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) allows you to promote an object which merges the old `$$ROOT` and `myValues` into root level.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will give this a try.